# Configuraciones de ítems por código usando arquitectura MVVM en Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Utilizando el modelo de arquitectura MVVM. Tengo un elemento que va a ser la home. Lo voy a agrupar todo y el directorio del proyecto quedaría así:

```
-project
   -HomeView
       -Model
       -ViewModel
       -View
           -HomeView.xib
```

Utilizando xib para las vistas, ahora me gustaría saber donde tendría que ir el código responsable de, por ejemplo, customizar un label que implemente en esa view. Un label que tuviese otra font, u otro color.

En MVVM, ¿en el Model estaría la lógica pura y dura, y en el ViewModel estaría la encargada de mostrar correctamente diferente información en la view, proveniente del Model?

Comment: Utilizas un TableViewController o un ViewController para mostrar tu label?

Comment: @Bicho utilizo un ViewController

Comment: Puedes agregar un poco del código que tienes, para que no califiquen negativa tu pregunta ni la reporten. No debe ser todo, lo más relevante.

Comment: Voy a modificar la pregunta, que creo que me estoy explicando mal @Bicho

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta corta es que en la arquitectura MVVM, las configuraciones de las vistas viven en View. Donde se encuentra tu .xib, debería existir un archivo .swift que sería el “controller” de la vista que quieres crear. Ese “controller” sería el encargado del estilo de la vista.